# How can a field be rendered as a <meta> element?

Tags: 7, theming, entities

### The problem:

I would like to be able to manage custom `<meta>` elements, on a per-item basis in a custom theme. An example would be for adding open graph and schema tags, but I'm really looking for a generic solution.

I'm aware of custom modules, such as [Meta Tags](http://drupal.org/project/metatag), but I'd rather avoid relying on other modules at this point.

### What I've Tried:

After looking at [`them_field`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/theme_field/7) it looked as though I should create a custom theme function for my custom field (`field_test` being used for this example). The theme function could add a `<meta>` tag and not return any content to be rendered.

<sub>In `template.php`:</sub>

```
<?php
//I *did* actually use my theme name instead of THEMENAME
function THEMENAME_field__field_test($vars) {
    drupal_add_html_head(array(
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => array(
            'content' => drupal_render($vars['items'][0]),
            'name' => 'test'
        )
    ), 'test');

    //I figured this would prevent the field from being rendered inline
    return '';
}
```

Using that code the custom `<meta>` element *was* correctly added to the `<head>`. Nevertheless, the field was still rendered on the page.

If I changed the output to:

```
return ' ';
```

The content was no longer rendered to the page, but an unnecessary space character would be output where the field was to be rendered.

Is there a better way to render a field as a `<meta>` element?
-or-
How can I prevent this themed field from rendering inline?

Answer (score -1):

try to return drupal_add_html_head array directly

```
<?php

function THEMENAME_field__field_test($vars) {
    return drupal_add_html_head(array(
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => array(
            'content' => drupal_render($vars['items'][0]),
            'name' => 'test'
        )
    ), 'test');
 }
```

Comment: This produced `Array` in the output.

Comment: then use return drupal_render( your array)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, could you update your answer with details?